# How to include fake API from function to React.JS app

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

I don't know how to include the fake date from existing function. I create an app with redux. And simple tests works.

When I include a date to HTML and call function `FruitasticApi` everything works. But if I want to import to the component I get errors, because I don't have an export in my fake date file

I have `FruitasticApi.js`( where I have some arrays with data).

This is FruitastaticApi.js

```js
(function(container) {
  var names = [
    'Chris', 'Svetla', 'Duncan', 'Vlad', 'Dennis', 'Amir', 'Kunjan', 'Aaron', 'Kirby', 'Michael',
    'Bryan', 'Edward', 'Stan', 'Eric', 'Jennifer', 'Kristy', 'Jason', 'Phoebe', 'Kate', 'Denise',
    'Abigail', 'Ethan', 'Lucia', 'Harry', 'David', 'Cameron', 'Erica', 'Sophie', 'Francis', 'Brian',
    'Paco', 'Luke', 'Margie', 'Sacha', 'Desmond', 'Ruby', 'Wanda', 'Rosalie', 'Angel', 'Layla', 'Flynn',
    'Anthony', 'Jasmine', 'Janie', 'Debbie', 'Keith', 'Porter', 'Francisco', 'Javier', 'Rudolph'
  ];
  var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTVWY'.split('');
  var fruits = [
    'blackberries', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'watermelon', 'cherries', 'mango',
    'grapes', 'apple', 'orange', 'cantaloupe', 'strawberries', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'pomegranate'
  ];

  var fruitsAPI = {
    get: function(callback) {
      var iter = 30 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50);

      var fruitIter = 3 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
      var availFruits = pickFruits(fruitIter);

      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        var randF = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        var randL = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        var randFruit = Math.floor(Math.random() * availFruits.length);
        arr[i] = {
          name: names[randF] + ' ' + letters[randL] + '.',
          favoriteFruit: availFruits[randFruit]
        }
      }
      var timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 100;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (callback) {
          callback(arr);
        }
      }, timeout);
    }
  };

  function pickFruits(num) {
    var availFruits = [];
    var rerun = true;
    while (rerun) {
      for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
        availFruits.push(fruits[index]);
      }
      var seen = availFruits[0];
      for (var i = 1; i < availFruits.length; i++) {
        if (availFruits[i] !== seen) {
          rerun = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return availFruits;
  }

  container.FruitasticApi = fruitsAPI;
})(window);
```

This is what I tried to do:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { simpleAction } from './actions/fruitaStaticAPI';
import { FruitasticApi } from './FruitasticApi'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './main.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(FruitasticApi)
    return (
      <div className="App">


      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction())
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This is my task:
Load data by calling `FruitasticApi.get()`.

Comment: What''s the error you get?

Comment: Console.log: undefined

Comment: `import { Fruit } from './FruitasticApi'`?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can `export` within isolated function .

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `FruitasticApi.js` as ({...})(window)? Why don't you have a normal function inside?

Comment: I think too...
The client wants me to use React, redux to include this data.
I need to load this function `FruitasticApi.get()` and I will get all necessary data

Comment: If you're putting it on the window and you don't export it, you can remove this line: `import { FruitasticApi } from './FruitasticApi'` and just call to `window. FruitasticApi.get()`

Comment: @JoseA.Ayllón I understand you. Do you have suggestion about how to change and call `fruitsAPI` ?

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't understand you, what do you mean? How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a normal `export` without isolation scope:

```js
(function(container) {
//...
})(window);
```

And just export (the last line in the file)

```
export const FruitasticApi = fruitsAPI;
```

And then, you can import it in the component file:

```
import { FruitasticApi } from './FruitasticApi'
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wekuan

**Don't forget to open the console**

---

Or, if you must use the isolation approach, your code assign the `FruitasticApi` to the window

```
container.FruitasticApi = fruitsAPI;
```

So, you can get it in your component file using

```
console.log(window.FruitasticApi);
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wshnyh

Comment: Thank you! I think I must use your solution. FruitastaticApi.js must be changed a little bit.

Comment: I have one more question for you, sorry...
Do you know how I can take arrays from functions now? I don't know how to call it

Comment: Do you mean to export the arrays `names`, `letters` and `fruits`? If you take the module approach (1st one) you can export them like `export const names = [...]`. If you take the global variables (on window) approach (2nd one), you can assign it to the `window` too. `container.name = [...]`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Thank you, I did on this way
`window.FruitasticApi.get((fruit) => {
      console.log(fruit)
      dispatch({ type: 'SIMPLE_ACTION', payload: fruit })
    })`

Comment: So you can put the arrays on the `window` too. For example: `window.names = ['Chris', 'Svetla', 'Duncan'...]` and in the component's script you can access the array with `console.log(window.names)`.

Comment: And by the way, **I really recommend you to use modules and not global variables** (the other way, because of bundling and build and so. If you want more info about it, get the details in [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu?tab=profile)).

Answer (score 0):

You should have your FruitasticApi as a const function like this:

```js
export const FruitasticApi = callback => {
  var names = [
    'Chris',
    'Svetla',
    'Duncan',
    'Vlad',
    'Dennis',
    'Amir',
    'Kunjan',
    'Aaron',
    'Kirby',
    'Michael',
    'Bryan',
    'Edward',
    'Stan',
    'Eric',
    'Jennifer',
    'Kristy',
    'Jason',
    'Phoebe',
    'Kate',
    'Denise',
    'Abigail',
    'Ethan',
    'Lucia',
    'Harry',
    'David',
    'Cameron',
    'Erica',
    'Sophie',
    'Francis',
    'Brian',
    'Paco',
    'Luke',
    'Margie',
    'Sacha',
    'Desmond',
    'Ruby',
    'Wanda',
    'Rosalie',
    'Angel',
    'Layla',
    'Flynn',
    'Anthony',
    'Jasmine',
    'Janie',
    'Debbie',
    'Keith',
    'Porter',
    'Francisco',
    'Javier',
    'Rudolph',
  ];
  var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTVWY'.split('');
  var fruits = [
    'blackberries',
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'banana',
    'pear',
    'watermelon',
    'cherries',
    'mango',
    'grapes',
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'cantaloupe',
    'strawberries',
    'kiwi',
    'pineapple',
    'pomegranate',
  ];

  var fruitsAPI = {
    get: function(callback) {
      var iter = 30 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50);

      var fruitIter = 3 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
      var availFruits = pickFruits(fruitIter);

      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        var randF = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        var randL = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
        var randFruit = Math.floor(Math.random() * availFruits.length);
        arr[i] = {
          name: names[randF] + ' ' + letters[randL] + '.',
          favoriteFruit: availFruits[randFruit],
        };
      }
      var timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 100;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (callback) {
          callback(arr);
        }
      }, timeout);
    },
  };

  function pickFruits(num) {
    var availFruits = [];
    var rerun = true;
    while (rerun) {
      for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
        availFruits.push(fruits[index]);
      }
      var seen = availFruits[0];
      for (var i = 1; i < availFruits.length; i++) {
        if (availFruits[i] !== seen) {
          rerun = false;
        }
      }
    }
    return availFruits;
  }

  return fruitsAPI.get(callback);
};
```

Now if you try to call it from your component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { simpleAction } from './actions/fruitaStaticAPI';
import { FruitasticApi } from './FruitasticApi'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './main.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    FruitasticApi(data => console.log(data))
    return (
      <div className="App">


      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  simpleAction: () => dispatch(simpleAction())
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

You should be able to see the results in the console.